# Is a bracha required prior to eating nutritional yeast?

Tags: blessing

There is something called [nutritional yeast](http://kosherwoman.com/Menu_Items/Kitchen/Flavors%20&%20Ingredients/nutritionalYeast.html). It seems that it is generally used as an additive to recipes or as a seasoning.

If one ate this, plain, what bracha should he make prior to eating this? According to [this site](http://redstaryeast.com/science-yeast/what-is-yeast/), yeasts are fungi, so I assume that the bracha would be *shehakol* - similar to mushrooms. However, from what I could glean from my searches, there doesn't appear to be a habit or suggestion to eat plain yeast, and it seems to always be used in something else. Thus, it's possible that it may not be considered a "food" and perhaps requires no bracha at all.

Comment: Dunno.  ❧  For now, you could do this:  You could eat a small amount of some other food which definitely requires _shehakol_.  Then, you could eat your nutritional yeast afterwards.

Comment: Why would anyone eat nutritional yeast by itself?